# How does Venom survive the blast from the rocket?

Tags: plot-explanation, venom

In the final fight scene of the *Venom* movie, Venom takes down the whole spaceship which was going to take off and then protects Eddie from the blast. How did Venom survive that blast?

Comment: Sequel armour!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I watched that scene twice and I think when the rocket was going to blow, Venom hides himself in the body of Eddie and I think that's the reason Venom survived the blast.

Comment: But venom turned himself to a parachute and so he was destroyed by the fire.

Comment: only part of his body was the parachute. not everything

Answer (score 2):

If you want a more substantial answer, one can be found in the lore of the symbiotes. For that, you need to be familiar with the comics. The abridged version goes something like this: By the end of the film, the symbiote and Eddie had fully bonded; they had become a single organism. Although the explosion had incinerated most of the alien tissue, as long as Eddie survived, a small part of the symbiote survives (at a cellular level). With time, it would regenerate enough of it’s biomass to take form again.